# CSS menu not pushing in

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two push menu's: left and right. The right push menu is not working correctly when viewed on a mobile (issue 1 below). Additionally, neither menu's work in IE 11 (issue 2 below).

1. Mobile - On a mobile, when you open the left push menu and then
   close it the right menu pushes into view and you cannot get rid of
   it.
2. IE issue - In IE 11 the push menus do not appear, with the cause, as
   far as I can tell, being: position:fixed; as applied to
   menu-push-left and menu-push-right elements. I originally had
   position:absolute; but this would cause the menu-push-right element
   to just appear when opened in IE instead of "sliding" in. I have no
   idea why the position:fixed; does not work in this instance of IE.
   IE 7+, last I knew, supports position:fixed;

Could someone take a look at my code and tell me what I may have missed?

The JsFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/totaleeyou/0w5w4t4s/8/

```
body {
    color:#2c2c2c;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    font-size:1em;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}

body.has-active-menu-push-left,
body.has-active-menu-push-right {
    overflow:hidden;
}

body, header.scroll, header ul.logo, #menu-push-left, #menu-push-right, button.menu-close i.fa-times-circle-o, .page-masking {
    -webkit-transition:all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition:all 0.5s;
    -ms-transition:all 0.5s;
    -o-transition:all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
body.has-active-menu-push-left, #menu-push-left {
    -webkit-transform:translate(100%, 0);
    -moz-transform:translate(100%, 0);
    -ms-transform:translate(100%, 0);
    -o-transform:translate(100%, 0);
    transform:translate(100%, 0);
}
body.has-active-menu-push-right, #menu-push-right {
    -webkit-transform:translate(-100%, 0);
    -moz-transform:translate(-100%, 0);
    -ms-transform:translate(-100%, 0);
    -o-transform:translate(-100%, 0);
    transform:translate(-100%, 0);
}
@media only screen and (min-width:780px) {
    body.has-active-menu-push-left, #menu-push-left {
        -webkit-transform:translate(500px, 0);
        -moz-transform:translate(500px, 0);
        -ms-transform:translate(500px, 0);
        -o-transform:translate(500px, 0);
        transform:translate(500px, 0);
    }
    body.has-active-menu-push-right, #menu-push-right {
        -webkit-transform:translate(-500px, 0);
        -moz-transform:translate(-500px, 0);
        -ms-transform:translate(-500px, 0);
        -o-transform:translate(-500px, 0);
        transform:translate(-500px, 0);
    }
}

.wrapper {
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
}
@media only screen and (min-width:780px) {
    .wrapper {
        width:1000px;
        margin:0 auto;
        padding: 0 5px;
    }
}

#page-masking {
    position:fixed;
}
.page-mask {
    z-index:100;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    background-color:#bec4a6;
}
.page-mask.is-active {
    width:100%;
    height:100vh;
    opacity:.7;
        -webkit-transition:opacity .5s;
            transition:opacity .5s;
}
.close-container {
    width:100%;
    height:55px;
    padding:5px;
    position:relative;
}
button.menu-close {
    color:#fdbc5d;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:3em;
    position:absolute;
    top:5px;
    right:25px;
    display:block;
    border:none;
    background:none;
}

#menu-push-left,
#menu-push-right {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100vh;
    z-index:150;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y:auto;
    background-color:#0079c1;
}
#menu-push-left {
    left:-200%;
}
#menu-push-right {
    right:-200%;
}
@media only screen and (min-width:780px) {
    #menu-push-left {
        width:500px;
        left:-1000px;
    }
    #menu-push-right {
        width:500px;
        right:-1000px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I changed the position of your menues to 'fixed', and that seemed to do the trick =)

```
#menu-push-left, #menu-push-right {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 150;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-color: #0079c1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Repo. That seems to have fixed the push issue (item 1) item 2 still is a problem. If you reduce the with of the Results window on the jsFiddle you will see the issue.

Comment: Repo - I remember why I had the menus set to position:absolute; IE 11. In IE the push menus do not work. I have no idea why the position:fixed; does not work. IE 7+, last I knew, now supports position:fixed; but position:fixed does not work in this instance.